# Cannot create property on string Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello i would like some help regarding an error im encountering.
im using angular.
this is my code:

component.ts:

```
tagname: string = "";
newtagName: string ="";

tags: any[];
newtagsName:any[]=[""];
//OnSave Tag btn 
saveTag(index){
 console.log(this.tagname);
 console.log(this.newtagName);

 this.dataSvc.addTagDisplayName({newname: this.newtagName,tagname: this.tagname}).subscribe(result=> 
{
  if (result.error) {
    this.toastrSvc.danger(result.errorMsg, "Error")
  } else {
    this.toastrSvc.success("Tag Name Chnaged!");
  }
})

 }
```

html:

```
<nb-list>
                  <nb-list-item  class="min-padding" *ngFor="let t of tags;let i=index;">
                    <b>{{t}}:</b>
                    <input type="text "fullWidth  nbInput  [(ngModel)]="t.newtagsName">
                    <button class='save-btn' (click)='saveTag(i)' nbButton status="primary" >SAVE</button>
                  </nb-list-item>
                </nb-list>
```

Error:

```
Cannot create property 'newtagsName' on string 'foo' //foo is comming from DB.
```

Thanks for any help i want to fix the error and take all inputs and save them as different columns on DB.